# How to find the sum of largest odd factor of a number?

Tags: c++, math

I've a problem to find sum of largest odd factor of a number ( F(x) ) and F(x) = f(1)+f(2)+...+f(x). As you know the largest factor of 1 is 1, 2 is 1, 3 is 3, 4 is 1, and so on...

e.g The sum of largest odd factor of a number 6 is f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+f(4)+f(5)+f(6), that is 1+1+3+1+5+3 or 14.

And I want to try to solve a number until 2*10^9

So this is my code for the f(x) that get 82/100 before timeout

```
unsigned long long int biggestOddFactor(unsigned long long int n){
    //!(n & (n - 1))
    while(n%2 == 0){
        n /= 2;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This is the another method by [removing the zero on the last bit of a number](https://qr.ae/TUtjDk), but it only make 77/100

```
#include <bitset>

unsigned long long int biggestOddFactorUsingBinary(unsigned long long int n){
    std::string bin = std::bitset<32>(n).to_string();
    int delet = 0;
    for(int i = bin.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(bin[i] == '0'){
            delet += 1;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    bin = bin.substr(0, bin.length()-delet);
    return std::bitset<32>(bin).to_ulong();;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize my algorithm?

Comment: a lookup would probably be faster, the idea is this recursion `f(x)=x%2?f(x/2):x`

Comment: and you may also need `F(x)=f(x)+F(x-1)`

Comment: or maybe use something to count number of trailing zeros

Comment: You mean "odd factor", not "even factor", or?

Comment: Using recursion only make it slower.. I only get 36/100 using it

Comment: @KlausGütter ah right. Sorry, I've edit it

Comment: Why does it need to timeout?

Comment: "get 82/100 before timeout" what does this mean?

Comment: @n.m. It means his code processes 82 of the 100 test inputs before it uses up more time than allowed for the solution to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. The problem is not that you are finding the biggest odd factor too slowly, the problem is that your algorithm for finding the sum is too slow, not that this one part of it is too slow.

For example, the largest odd factor of every odd number is the number itself, and there's a formula for the sum of the first n odd numbers. Why are you not using that to halve the number of times you call `biggestOddFactor`? That's just for starters.

The largest odd factor of any even number is the same as that for half that number. So the sum of the largest odd factors of, say, 16, 14, 12, and 10 is the same as that for 8, 7, 6, and 5. Yet you compute these two ranges separately? Why?

And so on. You need to optimize your algorithm, not your implementation of a bad algorithm. The concepts above suggest several possible recursive implementations that will be much faster.

I just [very quickly whipped up a solution](https://ideone.com/TtJpaq) to this problem using a better algorithm and it's thousands of times faster than just calling `biggestOddFactor` on every number. Note that my solution is recursive.

You should *always* consider algorithmic optimizations before you try to micro-optimize an implementation. The payoff tends to be much greater and the result is much less fragile.

Comment: Did you mean that the largest factor of 16 is the same as the largest factor of 8? The sum of largest factors for 16 is `f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(15) + f(16) = 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 5 + 3 + 7 + 1 + 9 + 5 + 11 + 3 +  13 + 7 + 15 + 1 = 86` but for 8 is `f(1) + f(2) + ... f(7) + f(8) = 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 5 + 3 + 7 + 1 = 22`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I misunderstood, by *sum of the largest odd factors of, say, 16, 14, 12, and 10 is the same as that for 8, 7, 6, and 5* you meant `f(16) + f(14) + f(12) + f(10) = f(8) + f(7) + f(6) + f(5)`?

Comment: This is an excellent answer - for `2e9` it's not thousands of times faster but *millions* of times faster. Although I note that for `2e10` `naive()` and `smart()` return different values (`4 206 124 817 370 522 026` and `8 817 810 835 797 909 930` respectively). Is that perhaps due to overflow at `return (max * max - min * min)/4;`? I can't think what else would cause that disagreement...

Comment: @Ghost I suspect so. There are ways to modify that code to avoid an overflow if needed. `((max/2) * (max/2))-((min/2)*(min/2))` might help.